# copying file into wildcard folder using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to put some files into some particular folders that shares same identification (numbering).

File Pile_XX.jnl.txt to a folder XX_(FolderName), XX is the identification number.

This is what I did, but it does not work

```
for %%i in ( 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32) do (

echo copying Pile_%%i.jnl.txt

copy Pile_%%i.jnl.txt   %%i*/Comp/mdl/pile.jnl   

echo.

)
```

it says wrong syntax

thanks!

Comment: of course it doesn't work. Do you really think, `copy` accepts a wildcard directory as destination?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use another `for` to get the subdirectories and copy to them  one after the other:

```
echo off
for /l %%i in (3,1,32) do (
 echo --- %%i ---
 for /d %%d in (%%i_*) do ( 
  echo copy "Pile_%%i.jnl.txt" "%%d\comp\mdl\pile.jnl"
 )
)
```

Remove the `ECHO` if the output satisfies you.

(I changed your `%%i` loop to a `for /L` because it's shorter, but on the other hand, it works only for consecutive numbers)

Comment: Hi @Stephan, thanks for your suggestion. However, looks like it works at the first loop, the second loop does not work. It does not give any feedback (Pile_3.jnl.txt, Pile_4.jnl.txt, ........). The files are not copied also.

Comment: it works if I removed the second loop and just put the copy command in the first loop. However, it didn't do any wildcard directory, the directories are just plain 3,4,5...32 without any additional strings.

Comment: I WORKS..! sorry it was my mistake. Thanks @Stephan !!

Comment: forgot to remove the `ECHO`?  ;)

Comment: Nah, its too dumb to tell :D :D :D :D